# Handling a popup window using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, popup, selenium-webdriver

I have a circumstance in which clicking a link webpage opens a popup window. And after the popup window opens the focus is in the popup window and master window is disabled. And i am unable to get the control transferred to the popup window.
Please have a look at the following code.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click me")).click();// when this line of code is reached then a popup window opens.

System.out.println("After Clicking me"); // After the popup window opens this line of code is never executed.
```

I am unable to transfer the control from parent window to popup window. I am aware of the following command.

```
driver.switchTo().window("popup window");
```

But its not helping much. please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a code i use when i need to work with a following pop-up window, close it and go back to my main window. Of course it has been simplified for the purpose of this answer. It maintains a handle of the original window (main) so it can make a difference between the others.

It requires an explicit WebDriverWait because i did have problems during development that code got run before the window actually got open, so this might not be a ideal condition,

```java
function manipulatePopUp(final WebDriver driver, final WebDriverWait wait) {
    final String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.id("linkThatOpensPopUp")).click();

    wait.until(new ExpectedConditions<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return (d.getWindowHandles().size() != 1);
        }
    });

    for (String activeHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!activeHandle.equals(mainWindowHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(activeHandle);
        }
    }

    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about the wait.until method syntax and the logic in it?

Comment: By the way, driver.getWindowHandles() returns a Set not a List.

Comment: The wait basically keeps looping until the driver has more than one handle, by that means giving me the proper timing to be sure the pop-up is now ready to be interacted with.

Comment: That's a comfortable way to be assured that once it gets on the for() it will loop until upon finding a window that it's not my main one.

Comment: +1 Elegant IMO. Just a few typos: it should be new ExpectedCondition (singular). And above comment is correct, I used `for (Iterator<String> it = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) { ... }`.

Answer (score 9):

> driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click me")).click();// when this line of code is reached then a popup window opens.
>
> System.out.println("After Clicking me"); // After the popup window
>   opens this line of code is never executed.

The line of code is never executed because the process is waiting for the popup to be handled.

getWindowHandles() works properly in this situation.

Example:

```
//handle of the master window before clicking the link
String master = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click me")).click();

//logic for waiting for the popup, checking the size to become greater than 1 or breaking after sometime to avoid the infinite loop.
int timeCount = 1;

do
{
   driver.getWindowHandles();
   Thread.sleep(200);
   timeCount++;
   if ( timeCount > 50 ) 
   {
       break;
   }
}
while ( driver.getWindowHandles().size == 1 );

//Assigning the handles to a set
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
//Switching to the popup window.
for ( String handle : handles )
{
    if(!handle.equals(master))
    {
         driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```

Now driver is switched to the popup window. If the popup window has a frame then you need to switch to the frame before identifying elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class socialSignOn extends masterBaseClassNewSiteStage {

    @Test
    public void testSocialSignOn() throws Throwable {
        openParticularUrl("/my-lfc/join/user-details?user_type=free");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#socialSignOn > div.left.socialLogin.googleButton")).click();

        String MainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

        for (String activeHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!activeHandle.equals(MainWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(activeHandle);
            }
        }
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Email")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#next")).click();
        pauseFiveSeconds();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Passwd")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#signIn")).click();
        pauseOneSecond();
        driver.switchTo().window(MainWindow);
        pauseTenSeconds();
        closeDriver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// delay : max number of seconds
new WebDriverWait(driver, delay * 1000).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
drive`enter code here`r.switchTo().alert().accept();
```