# How to switch to a new pop-up window using selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I need to automate the following test:
after the login on the web page a new pop-up window (with app) opens and all steps should be done in this new window.

Question:
how to code to switch from the current login window to the new pop-up window?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939298/handling-a-popup-window-using-selenium

Comment: unfortunately, it's not the same case. In my case, I need to change focus to pop up and continue the test in pop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle child window then you have to use handles in seleneium, Kindly refer below code:

```
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle

//Perform action on your parent window 
//Perform clcik() action on your parent window that opens a new window    

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

         if(!winHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle))
         {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // Here yor switching control to child window so that you can perform action on child window
            System.out.println("Title of the new window: " +
            driver.getTitle());
            //code to do something on new window
            System.out.println("Closing the new window...");
            driver.close();
         }

   }   

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
System.out.println("Parent window URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Comment: there is a problem. IE closes the parent window (no idea why). sometimes the test works, sometimes it fails with the error NoSuchWindowException: Window is closed in the code line: String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

Comment: what issue are you  facing ?

Comment: it looks like the app and IE 11 is doing the following: after the log-in in the parent window it opens a new pop-up window and closes the parent one without focus in the new pop-up window.
If I add the code you mention above, sometime it works, sometime it does not. Without your code it shows an error: NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser.

Comment: Check with chrome and firefox because if parent window is closinng on them then you need to raise this with dev team

Comment: App is compatible with IE only :(
probably I can just modify this driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); without checking the parent window?

Comment: I would say first check expected behavior if you want to continue with child window then don't switch back to parent window again

Comment: It looks like this is IE issue. Many thanks for your help!